# Visual C# 2010 Express Output Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there Output window in C# 2010 Express? I don't see it in the View menu.

Comment: check under debug windows would be my next guess

Comment: See also: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/10/express-2010-basic-and-expert-settings.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>

It is on the menu in expert mode; Tools => Settings => Expert Settings.

In reality most of the useful options are in expert mode; I can't think of a sane reason to use basic mode, nor why it is the default (instead perhaps of asking me "Have you ever programmed before?")

Comment: Apologies for potential spam, but what's the markup for producing the "keyboard key" effect?

Comment: @AndyC wrap in kbd tags (you can view source and see)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why I was missing a large chunk of useful functionality ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + W, O will open the Output window if it's available.

Answer (score 3):

Menu:  Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General

Show Output window when build starts Check box available.Select the check box.
Output will be Enabled...